# React Native fill View or Text with dots

Tags: react-native, material-design

I'm trying to replicate this dots next to the name of the ingredient.

I got this example from [Basil - Material Design](https://material.io/design/material-studies/basil.html#layout).

[image]

How can I add this dots without knowing width of the `View` / `Text`?

Comment: Maybe you can just place a View after the Text with flex 1 and set border bottom for View with dotted border style. You can give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea! You can use one line text to achieve it?
Let middle text in a Text tag, and then set it numberOfLines={1} like below.

```
<Text numberOfLines={1}>
Basil ...................................................................
</Text>
```

This will generate redundant string ".........." to "..." like:

```
Basil ..................................
```

Comment: Whether both the dots will look the same? Hardcoded one and the one which is done by RN